# Angular js - $routeProvider - how to get it to resolve on routeChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, resolve, route-provider

I'm reading the Angular documentation for `$routeProvider` and I the parameters say:

> `resolve` - {Object.=} - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of
>   these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to
>   be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the
>   values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess
>   event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the
>   `$routeChangeError` event is fired. The map object is:
>
> `key` – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the
>   controller. factory - {string|function}: If string then it is an alias
>   for a service. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the
>   return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise,
>   it is resolved before its value is injected into the controller. Be
>   aware that ngRoute.$routeParams will still refer to the previous route
>   within these resolve functions. Use $route.current.params to access
>   the new route parameters, instead.

So is there any way to `resolve` in routeProvider when `routeChangeStart` instead of when `routeChangeSuccess` ?

To explain my reasoning - I would like to run the resolve on routeChangeStart because i'm setting up config params for all my app and i would like to have them accessible as soon as possible, and ChangeSuccess is a step later.

my code is actually so simple:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/',{
   templateUrl:'amagic_template.html',
   controller:'Ctrl',
   resolve: {
    load: function (configFactory) {
      return configFactory.load(); // promises in here 
    } 
   }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why you'd like this? The depencencies resolved are for the _controller_, which you run _after_ the change has succeeded. Why do you need these dependencies before? For what use?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sure sorry i added more infos !

Comment: You didnt explain what the problem was.If you really need to do something on routeChangeStart, listen that event.Because i dont see the issue. I mean you didnt explain what specific issue you had so that routeChangeSuccess is unfit.

Comment: @mpm the problem imho its clear, as per DOC resolve will run at routeCHangeSuccess right? now , how to make it run at ChangeStart? impossible? need i to run() or something else promises?

Comment: you cant resolve on routeChangeStart,period.You could either fork angular-route and change it,or listen routeChangeStart and do what you need to do there.

Comment: @mpm what i mean is doing "on routeChangeStart" out of routeProvider !? and how to specify i need the promises to resolve before routeProvider fires routeChangeSuccess in there?

Comment: @mpm do you understand the use case OP has? Can you explain it?